# How to use application console during debug in Clion?

Tags: clion

I am using Clion 2017.1.1, Windows 7 64-bit, MinGW 5. When I debug a program, it uses system console. When I run a program, it uses application console. Personally, I prefer the built-in application console since it keeps the console cout history after program termination. In this way, I don't need to add a system("pause") to my code. So, how do I use application console for debugging?

Comment: There's no easy way to do that on Windows, unfortunately. Here's the corresponding request: [CPP-8175](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8175) Applications Output is redirected to separate Console Window during Debugging

Comment: @Eldar Abusalimov So, there is a way to do that on Windows?

Comment: I mean it's not obvious how to implement this (I'm one of CLion developers). There is a hackish way to do that (similar to how Eclipse handles it), but it is kind of fragile, so we need to consider it more thoroughly. Until then there's no any workaround I'm aware of to suggest you, unfortunately.